# Are "using" statements "bad code"?

Tags: c#, exception, using-statement

I have read that a using like this:

```
using (myObject)
{
   myObject.DoStuff();
}
```

Can be thought of like this:

```
try
{
   myObject.DoStuff();
}
finally
{
   myobject.Dispose()
}
```

So if myObejct.DoStuff throws `ExceptionA` and then myObject.Dispose() also throws an exception (ExceptionB) then `ExceptionA` will be lost.  (See the [MSDN examples here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx) for a better description.)

Does this mean that if the code inside a using block code could throw an exception *(which is most code right?)* then a `using` statement is a bad practice?

Comment: "Can be thought of like this" is something of an understatement. :)

Comment: What business does `Dispose` have throwing an exception?

Comment: @blzm It's not exactly that code.. .that is a simplified version of the code a using statement creates.

Comment: Personally I prefer using encapsulated with a try/catch in the case the Dispose will throw an exception. But as others have mentioned already. Something is really wrong if the Dispose is throwing an exception in the first place.

Comment: @BenVoigt - some Dispose calls do throw exceptions.  See the link zugbo put in his answer (from Marc Gravell)

Comment: @Vaccano: I didn't say that `Dispose` can't throw an exception, I said it has no business doing so.  Those objects are broken.  Luckily Marc showed a way to fix them with a wrapper object.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Does this mean that if the code inside a using block code could throw an exception (which is most code right?) then a using statement is a bad practice?

No.

> and then myObject.Dispose() also throws an exception

This is really the crux of your question.

This is the "bad practice" here.  `IDisposable.Dispose` implementations should really be designed so that they don't raise exceptions except in situations which are truly unrecoverable.

Since `IDisposable` is really intended to release the resource in question, the main issue should be making sure that this implementation won't throw under most circumstances.  Having a cleanup method throw will cause a lot of grief - and is the reason why the [using statement shouldn't be used with WCF clients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx), etc.

That being said, I don't think the using statement itself is a bad practice.  In fact, it tends to be a very good practice, as it avoids a very common pitfall (missing the disposable of a resource in the case of an exception).

Comment: +1, Throwing from a `Dispose` call is the equivalent of throwing from a C++ destructor. Makes it impossible for calling code to be correct when you consider collections destructable items

Answer (score 7):

`using` statements ensure that types that implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) are disposed of correctly (that is, it is [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for a correct implementation of the [Dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx)).

They are very much **good practice**.

Having a *Dispose* function throw *is* bad practice.

Comment: There was a specific concern about exceptions in the question.

Answer (score 6):

This is a common problem in WCF, where Dispose() frequently throws exceptions. There's a way of wrapping the disposable so that you can continue to get the benefits of the using() statement, without risking an exception being lost. It essentially swallows any exception thrown during Dispose, so that the original exception is always the one that gets thrown to the higher context.

http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/dontdontuse-using.html

Answer (score 2):

A fundamental limitation with exception handling in .net is that since it is patterned off the C++ exception-handling model, all information related to the current exception context has to be encapsulated in a single exception object; indeed, in C#, all information related to whether or not an exception should be caught has to be encapsulated in a single exception object's *type*.  Further, in C#, the only way to even find out an exception has occurred is to agree to catch it, and there is no way to indicate declaratively that one wishes to act upon the exception but has no intention of handling it sufficiently for it to be considered "resolved".  The cited difficulties with "using" stem from these limitations.

In the real world, it's possible for things to occur during `Dispose()` which should disrupt the flow of any code which isn't expecting them.  Such occurrences should generally be exceptions.  Unfortunately, if `Dispose` is running because some other exception occurred, and an exception occurs within it, one only has three practical courses of action in C#:

1. Lose all information about the exception which caused `Dispose` to run, since there is no way for `Dispose` or the code calling it to get that information, and any exception which occurs within a `finally` block will destroy any information about any previously-pending instruction.

   Stifle the exception which occurred within `Dispose`--one could log it somewhere, but unless the caller explicitly checks the log, it will have no clue that an exception occurred.

   Catch any and all types of exception, grab its type to a variable, and rethrow; act upon the variable in question within the `finally` block.

In vb.net, there's a fourth possibility which has better semantics, but requires icky-looking code: `Exception` and use exception filters to latch, without catching, any exception that occurs to a variable and, as with #3 above, act upon that variable in the "finally" block.

The "using" statement offers the first semantics listed above.  In some situations, the other approaches may be better.  I wish vb and C# would offer a version of the "finally" statement which accepted a parameter of type `Exception`.  It could allow the #4 semantics above (which are semantically the nicest) to be available without ugly code.